# Can I use Netflix like payment method in my Google playstore app to bypass google in app payments?

Tags: android, google-play, stripe-payments, subscription, in-app-subscription

I want to **bypass google in app payment method** as I have to create subscriptions that crossed max limits google play allows i.e; **400 USD**. The approach I am using is to register user on my web portal and subscribed them on web instead of app, Does google allows it?